# IR Remote code for Arduino

Tags: infrared, arduino, library, remote

I've just hidden away our entertainment centre electronics including our Infrared controlled DVD Player, Amp and Mac Mini .

I was wondering if there is any IR Remote code for Arduino, that I can use to eventually control the entertainment centre. I plan to write a simple iPhone app, that talks to an Arduino with an Ethernet shield.

Comment: I don't understand what you need the ethernet for. If you're using the Mac Mini to receive the commands from the iPhone over wifi, you can just send them to the Arduino via USB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help: [Arduino Forum: RC5 infrared remote](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1209565937)

I suspect the Mac Mini will not respond to the same sort of signals that your audio equipment does.

Comment: RC5 is used for Phillips equipment. If OPs DVD player, amp, etc is of different brands, this code may not work. [There are several IR remote protocol standards out there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_IR).

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article about IR with Arduino on the PragPub Issue 13, July 2010 here: http://www.pragprog.com/magazines